# Elastic search return the most recent item per term

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

My index has a `created_at` date field, and another field `account_id`. How do I get the most recent document for each account?

I only found the [term aggregate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) which aggregates per term, but it returns counts of items per term. Instead I need to sort and return the 1st result per term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the term aggregation with the [top hits sub aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) to fetch the latest documents in each `account_id`.

term aggregation will create a bucket per account and later on you can sort all the documents in each bucket based on `created_at` and fetch just 1 document using **top hits sub aggregation**.

Example with data

**Index sample data**

```
{
  "date_field": "2022-10-31T00:00:00Z",
  "account_id" :1 
}

{
  "date_field": "2023-01-31T00:00:00Z",
  "account_id" :1 
}

{
  "date_field": "2023-01-31T00:00:00Z",
  "account_id" :2 
}

{
  "date_field": "2023-02-28T00:00:00Z",
  "account_id" :2 
}

{
  "date_field": "2023-03-09T00:00:00Z",
  "account_id" :4
}
```

Query to fetch the **latest document per account`

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "unique_account_ids": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "account_id"
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "latest_per_account": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "from": 0,
                        "size": 1,
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "date_field": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
 "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": 1,
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "latest_per_account": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 2,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": null,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "75680182",
                                    "_id": "2",
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "date_field": "2023-01-31T00:00:00Z",
                                        "account_id": 1
                                    },
                                    "sort": [
                                        1675123200000
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": 2,
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "latest_per_account": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 2,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": null,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "75680182",
                                    "_id": "4",
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "date_field": "2023-02-28T00:00:00Z",
                                        "account_id": 2
                                    },
                                    "sort": [
                                        1677542400000
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": 4,
                    "doc_count": 1,
                    "latest_per_account": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 1,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": null,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "75680182",
                                    "_id": "5",
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "date_field": "2023-03-09T00:00:00Z",
                                        "account_id": 4
                                    },
                                    "sort": [
                                        1678320000000
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
```